# How to create a loop to check and update the data in a DataFrame until a given result is obtained?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

for example, I have the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'a', 'level': 8}, {'name': 'b', 'level': 11}, {'name': 'c', 'level': 15}])
print(df)
top = 3
```

I need to create a loop that will check the value in the `df['level']` column, if the value is greater than the value in the variable `top`, then subtract 1 from this value, then update the data in the `df['level']` column. After the update, I need to check and update the data in the `df['level']` column again, and so on until the values in the `df['level']` column are equal to 1, 2 or 3. The very essence is to loop through all DataFrame values in the df['level'] column, compare, subtract and update the column, and not take only one value in the df['level'] column and get the desired result and only then move on to another value.

I understand that this is stupidly written, but the point is that the code conveys the logic of what I want to do:

```
while True:
    for i in df['level']: 
        if i > top:
            change = i - 1
            df.loc[df['level'] == i, 'level'] = change
        else:
            pass

    for i in df['level']:
        if i > top:
            change = i - 1
            df.loc[df['level'] == i, 'level'] = change
        else:
            pass

    for i in df['level']:
        if i > top:
            change = i - 1
            df.loc[df['level'] == i, 'level'] = change
        else:
            pass
    break

print(df)
```

In end I need the next result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpFBQ.png)

Comment: Why not just make value = top, instead those loops?

Comment: Yeah, I am struggling to follow the point of this as well.

Comment: The algorithm could be written in two lines (`while df.level.gt(top).any(): df.level -= df.level.gt(top)`) but what are you actually trying to do? Looks like an XY-problem to me.

Comment: @fsimonjetz hi, your answer made me understand how to stop the loop and how to give it a condition, that's all I need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

## -----------------------I option

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'a', 'level': 5}, {'name': 'b', 'level': 8}, {'name': 'c', 'level': 12}])
top = 3

while df['level'].gt(top).any():
        df['level'].gt(top).any()
        df['level'] -= df['level'].gt(top)
        print(df)
```

## ----------------------- II option

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'a', 'level': 5}, {'name': 'b', 'level': 8}, {'name': 'c', 'level': 12}])
top = 3

while df['level'].gt(top).any():
        for i in df['level']:
                if i > top:
                        change = i - 1
                        df.loc[df['level'] == i, 'level'] = change
                else:
                        pass
        print(df)
```

Comment: Glad if that gave you the hint you were looking for! I still wonder why you do it like that when you can do `df['level'] = top` as a Luis Alejandro Vargas Ramos commented? Or [`df.level.clip(upper=3)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) if you want to limit the series to a certain top value. I'm not being snarky, just genuinely curious.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).